# Rails: Database design for a unique set of items with variable length

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have a table of Items. There will likely be around 5 items in this table and I don't expect it to grow much beyond that. I have another table called Orders with hundreds of thousands of rows. Each order needs to reference some combination of the 5 items (could be 0 Items (null), could be all 5 or somewhere in between). No item can be counted twice and the order of items is irrelevant. This is a many-to-many relationship.

I want to capitalize on the fact that the combination of Items are finite. So if an Order has already referenced a particular combination of items, a second Order can reference the same set of items instead of duplicating the many-to-many associations in the join table. With so many Orders the items_orders join table would be huge and unnecessarily I believe.

How would you solve this problem?

Comment: You're solving a perceived problem, not an actual problem. Don't worry about it. Go finish your application, and if you run into an actual problem with this later, fix it then.

Comment: I agree that its a waste of time to solve problems or provide features that are not needed for sure. This problem, however, is not perceived, its imminent. I also agree that performance problems can be left til the end of development to be addressed. I'm done with everything else.

Comment: @Ben I don't think your question is very clear. You've essentially stated that you have solved the problem, but then ask how to solve it. What exactly are you trying to address? Performance? Storage size?

Comment: Order belongs_to ItemCollection. ItemCollection HABTM Items. Items HABTM ItemCollections. I have a custom validation which keeps the join table free of duplicates unless another process writes to the join table between the execution of the validation and a save.

Comment: Storage size was my main concern, though as Walter explains, its not that much space.

Comment: I thought somebody might have a more fool proof way than I did it, but maybe not since it now seems rare others would be bothered by join duplications. Anybody?

Answer (score 1):

Database tables can handle millions, if not billions of records. I think what @coreyward was getting at is that you shouldn't prematurely optimize code. Build it in a way that feels right to you and address performance issues as they arise. Plus, there's always a chance that by the time you need to address the performance, you'll want to change your application or database anyway. The time you saved by not trying to squeeze every last bit of performance out up front can then be used to fix the real issues.

Comment: I should have given more background to my question. :) I have a solution which I did not share so not to bias answers. The problem is not actually Items and Orders (used for simplicity), but rather my companies internal data which has not changed in 20 years. I'm taking a fresh look at implementing this mature data model more efficiently in rails. Now lets talk tech!

Comment: ...and one more thing.. my company is cheap so disk space is a concern.

Comment: How big is the database now and how much are you trying to reduce it by?

Comment: How much space will a million records take in the junction table. If each row requires 16 bytes, then a million rows will take 16 megabytes. Throw in another 4 megabytes for indexes and you've got 20 megabytes. How much can that cost your company?

Comment: I've got 1GB to work in. I didn't realize a million records would take so little space.

Answer (score 1):

To tally up the combinations:

- 1 combination of 5 items
- 5 combinations of 4 items
- 10 combinations of 3 items
- 10 combinations of 2 items
- 5 combinations of 1 item

So you would like to fix a table of 31 different combinations of the 5 items. Then you would have a table

```
class Combo < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :items
   has_many :orders
end
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :item
end
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :combo
end
```

And this seems good because your tables are nice and compact. The Item table is bounded at 5 items, the Combo table is bounded at 31 items, and the Order table varies to 1000000s of entries.

You could simplify further and get rid of the Item and Combo tables altogether and just hard-code them. After all, they are both bounded at a pretty small number. An analogy is if you have  an application which needs to do factorial calculations up to 100, you can make it very fast by just having a hard-coded lookup table.

This solution has a couple of problems. Your order provisioning software must be aware of all of the combinations and determine which one the user has chosen. So it is just a lookup table or a chained condition statement with 31 variations. Possible, but error-prone. Y

The other problem is that if you ever need to change combinations or have combinations where you can pick more than one of any item, then you will experience the need to write more code, and the number increases combinatorically with each additional combination allowed. And you have to hard-code them all.

You need to determine if your time writing code and fixing bugs is cheaper or more expensive than merely paying for a join table entry for each item associated with an order.  In my situation, coding is much more expensive, so, I'd just choose a structure which looks like this.

```
class ItemOrder < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :item
   belongs_to :order
end
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :item_combo
end
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :item_combo
end
```